# How to convert a String to an integer without losing preceding zeroes in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a String with preceding zeroes into an integer (or, let's say, a `BigDecimal`). But the zeroes are truncated when the String is converted. Please help me to convert without losing zeroes.

Comment: Integers do not contain information about preceding zeroes

Comment: I think you can't. Number have no "leading zero" information stored.

Comment: you can't store `001` in java integer.

Comment: Keep the string or calculate the number of zero and store it in a variable.

Comment: Why do you want the leading zeroes? If your requirement is to print the number with a fixed amount of digits later (e.g., `003453` if you require 6 digits), it’s just a matter of printing the number that way. `String.format()` or `System.out.format()` can do that, for example.

Comment: You need to learn to keep two concepts apart: the value of an integer and the display of it. `int` or `BigDecimal` can only contain the value, not the display. So the same `int` can be displayed as `7`, `007`, `+7` and in many other ways.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html) Oracle explains how integers are stored.

> - int, whose values are 32-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero

and also

> The values of the integral types of the Java Virtual Machine are:
>
> - For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647 (-2^31 to 2^31 - 1), inclusive

show that they only store the number, with 32 bits you can only store where you are in the range of -2147483648 to 2147483647.

So integers don't contain information about preceding zeroes. You had to store it separately.

```
String s = "0002314";
int precedingZeroes = 0;    

for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if(c == '+' || c == '-') {
        // Allowed, but no zero -> continue
        continue;
    }
    if(c == '0') {
        zeroes++; // We found a zero, increment counter
        continue;
    }
    // This is not a sign and no zero; we have non-zero digits now
    // (or it would be an ill-formed integer) so the other zeroes
    // are no preceding ones; -> break the loop, that's it
    break;
}

int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

So you have to store both the number and the number of zeroes. Note that this only works for decimal numbers.